# Yaml dump without new line

Tags: python, yaml

I am not sure if rules for Yaml dictates new line as a must have, But I am having an issue with the new line characters in the Yaml serialized string. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
yaml.dump(my_python_dict)
```

Returns:

```
"---\nasset_data:\n- {assetDefaultScenePath: 'C:\\\\data\\\\my_newfile.ma',\n  assetName: new_asset}\n- {assetDefaultScenePath: 'C:\\\\assetA.ma',\n  assetName: assetA.ma}\naudio_dir: ''\nbg_dir: ''\ndestination: ''\nepisode: '00'\nprod: test\n"
```

The issue is the YAML string is generated from Ruby and is passed through an intermediate scripting language (MEL) before it reaches Python. The intermediate language cannot understand Yaml and computes all the "\n" and fails. I was wondering if there is a way to dump Yaml without a newline character? I am guessing that would cause issues at load. I am currently out of idea's and any recommendation would be helpful.

Here is the detail on how things are tied up.
The ruby code will build a Windows Command line and execute it.

```
"Mayabatch" -command "source \"C:/cygwin/home/workspace/bpt-maya/src/bd_lay/generate.mel\";generate(\”{SERIALIZED_DICT}\")"
```

1. *SERIALIZED DICT* is where the YAML data needs to be added.
2. *generate.mel* has a python call with SERIALIZED DICT as argument
3. The Mayabatch does not support direct Python execution thats why it needs to be wrapped.
   JSON will fail here due to the double quotes that's why I need some other serialization.

Comment: Try fix the dump: yaml.dump(my_python_dict).replace('\n', ' ') - but I'd guess this breaks YAML syntax, so you really should get MEL fixed

Comment: MEL can't handle strings with new lines in them? It sounds like a problem w/ how the MEL script is written. But since the newlines are required, you could base64 encode the yaml in perl and decode it again in python.

Comment: Your YAML will no longer parse if you remove the newlines.  You could consider encoding the document (base64?) before passing it through your (broken?) environment.

Comment: I tried base64 but looks like the string still has newline characters. It wouldn't be a problem if Mel had some concept of raw strings. Is there any other encoding which uses single quotes similar to YAML?

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a super-set of JSON. So, a valid JSON is also a valid YAML (but valid YAML isn't necessarily valid JSON).

This fact may allow one to get around MEL's YAML-parsing limitations

```
>>> import yaml
>>> import json

>>> orig_yaml_txt = "---\nasset_data:\n- {assetDefaultScenePath: 'C:\\\\data\\\\my_newfile.ma',\n  assetName: new_asset}\n- {assetDefaultScenePath: 'C:\\\\assetA.ma',\n  assetName: assetA.ma}\naudio_dir: ''\nbg_dir: ''\ndestination: ''\nepisode: '00'\nprod: test\n"
>>> dict_1 = yaml.load(orig_yaml_txt)
>>> intermediate_json_txt = json.dumps(dict_1)
>>> dict_2 = yaml.load(intermediate_json_txt)
>>> dict_1 == dict_2
True
```

In the above snippet, I take your YAML-serialized text, load it into a python dictionary, then dump that to a json-serialized text, and then load it into a python dictionary using YAML to parse.

In your question, you state that the original YAML is generated from Ruby. Perhaps, instead of dumping YAML, you could dump JSON from Ruby, or add another step in the pipeline that converts the YAML to JSON before being fed to MEL.

Comment: That was my first attempt but passing JSON has different complications. Since the data is parsed via command line I would need escape sequence to work with double quotes. Thats why I need a serialization  which uses single quotes. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: what do you mean passed via command line, as in a piped? would you mind updating your question with how your data is being passed through the command line. Also, instead of "passing the data through the command line" maybe you could write the json/yaml to a file and read from the file in the next stage of the program

Comment: Edited the question. I know I can pass a file and that's what I did :) but its not ideal.